# can we see or accumulate antiparticles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, antimatter

I would like to know if we can see antiparticles with our bare eyes instead of a technological detector. I realize we cant see individual atoms or particles but enough photons grouped together, for example, let's us see light. Would it be the same for enough antiparticles grouped together? And if it has same mass as particle can be build something out of them if we accumulate enough together?

Comment: Photons are their own anti-particles, so we do see anti-particles.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically we can, I we had enough. But making and maintaining antimatter is hard. Also, if you aren't in a vacuum, you will just see bright light and energy.

Comment: as long as we can see it in light form thats good enough for me. that proves they exist in reality and aren't just theoretical.